# Merging polylines to next one in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, overlapping-features, polyline-creation

I'm working with QGIS and I'm not super familiar with that.
I created a Shapefile with several polylines. In some cases, my polylines do not match each other directly. For further proceedings, I would like that that line to match at the next point. The overlapping line I would like to adjust to the next line. To example underneath:

[image]

[image]

Any idea how I could do this best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the snapping and use the vertex tool to edit the string layer, than it's just a matter of editing the layer and putting all the vertexes you want together.

First you must activate the Snapping toolbar:
[image: First you must activate the Snapping toolbar]

Than you must turn it on just by clicking on it:
[image: Than you must turn it on just by clicking on it]

And finally just activate the editing of the layer you want to correct and enable the vertex tool:
[image]

Than you just select the vertex you want to move and connect with the snapping tool turned on[image]

It's my first answer here, hope it helps!